# How to combine multiple data frames having similar variable names into one data frame?

Tags: r

I was trying to write a code to combine multiple data frames(Approximately 100) where each data frame is stored with variable name output1, output2,....,output100. I want to merge these data frames into a single dataframe using rbind function but it is not working as I have to write each variable name again.

I need a suggestion to write all variable names in one go or in the form of a loop.

Problem:  I am trying to write the code as rbind(output1, output2, output3,....,output100) which is extremely long and tedious.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `mget`. *Example:*

Calling `ls()` gives you the object names in your workspace.

```
ls()
# [1] "n"       "out.lst"     "output.1"     "output.2"      "output.3"     "something.else"
```

Then use `mget` to grab the data frames by `pattern=` and `rbind` them using `do.call`.

```
output.long <- do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern="output.")))
#            x y z
# output.1.1 1 1 2
# output.1.2 5 5 4
# output.2.1 2 1 4
# output.2.2 5 4 1
# output.3.1 5 4 2
# output.3.2 2 2 3
```

---

*Toy data:*

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 3
out.lst <- setNames(replicate(n, data.frame(x=sample(1:5, 2), 
                                            y=sample(1:5, 2),
                                            z=sample(1:5, 2)), simplify=F),
                    paste0("output.", 1:n))
list2env(out.lst, env=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: You're welcome @SonalBajoriya, consider to [accept one answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use the tidyverse package, you can make `output` a list, then just write, say,  `combined <- bind_rows(output)`.  That fits naturally with using `lapply()` to create the data frames in the first place.

[Untested code]

```
library(tidyverse)

output <- lapply(1:length(inputFiles), function(x) read.csv(inputFiles[x]))
combined <- bind_rows(output)
```